# how do i prevent Resources can be accessed by old jwt?

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended

In my flask app, resources are handled with @jwt_required(). A new login creates a new JWT Token. I saved access_token in database and removed old jwt. But i can access the resources with the old jwt token. Is there any process where i can prevent using old jwt?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "destroy" an old token, it remains valid until the date specified during its creation. However, the **Flask-JWT** library offers the possibility of [blocking an old jwt](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/blocklist_and_token_revoking/).

To do this you will need to use **redis** or a **database**, which will be used by **Flask-JWT** as an archive to store the revoked tokens

**Redis**:

> If your only requirements are to check if a JWT has been revoked, our
> recommendation is to use redis. It is blazing fast, can be configured
> to persist data to disc, and can automatically clear out JWTs after
> they expire by utilizing the Time To Live (TTL) functionality when
> storing a JWT.

**Database**:

> If you need to keep track of information about revoked JWTs our
> recommendation is to utilize a database. This allows you to easily
> store and utilize metadata for revoked tokens, such as when it was
> revoked, who revoked it, can it be un-revoked, etc.

In the link I left you you can also find a complete example for both options